# MySQL DB structure: Should I create a table for each user or keep all the data in one table (small db. <20 users)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm new to MySQL and databases, and this question is more about best practices than exact code.

If I want to create a database that let's users register an "account" so they are then able to access and track the value of virtual goods in a video game, including selecting items from a list and marking them (thus requiring the choices to be associated with their account), Is it better to store the users choices in the same table that holds their username/account-info?  Or should the information be stored in a separate table with a reference to the associated account?
**Or** should I create a table for each user, instead of having one for registration/account info, and another for data, etc.?

Does the best practice for this vary with the expected number of users and/or amount of data?
Is there a way to set it up that allows for handling growth from 2 or 3 users to hundreds?

Comment: You do not want a table per user. It quickly becomes unmanageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to create one table for accounts, one table with choices that are referenced to that account with some type of token.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to create a new table for each user. You should have one table, and differentiate between the users using the data in the table (e.g., the userid, the username, etc).